# Wordpress Custom Post -> Show Children Category of current Parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<?php

$parent_cat_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 );
$parent_cat = get_terms('category',$parent_cat_arg);//category name

foreach ($parent_cat as $catVal) {

echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>'; //Parent Category

$child_arg = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $catVal->term_id );
$child_cat = get_terms( 'category', $child_arg );

echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $child_cat as $child_term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $child_term );
        echo '<li><a href=" ' . esc_url( $term_link ) . ' ">' .$child_term->name . '</a></li>'; //Child Category
    }
echo '</ul>';

}
?>
```

Which I use on the single-products.php template. This works fine, except it outputs all categories and all sub categories of my custom post type.

How do I get it to only show the sub categories of the current parent category?

Comment: I think you want only the category & their sub-categories which belongs to current single product post. right?

Comment: Correct Prateek

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the 'child_of'instead of 'parent' in your array?

$parent_cat_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'child_of' => 0 );

Comment: Doesnt work and it seems to duplicate every category/sub category

Comment: Sorry my bad you will need to pass the 'child_of' to the $child_arg  variable, so it should be: $child_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'child_of' => $catVal->term_id );